# Android permissions using admob - are they necessary?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, android-permissions

Could you help me?

I have a question about permission required by using admob in my application. Are these permissions really necessary? I've found some app on PlayStore they are using ads without any permissions? How can I do it?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Which permissions are you requesting?

Comment: I mean INERNET ACCESS permission. I found on Play Store some apps, they require no permissions, but ads are working normally. How is it possible?

Comment: @HSSDevelopers It doesn't sound possible. You need internet access in order to refresh adverts as well as to report click throughs. Without internet access, I'm pretty sure the AdMob ads don't even show (that's what happens when I have wifi disabled, anyhow). You can leave out location permissions which have to do with geographically directed advertising, but you need internet and network state.

Comment: Well it's possible, just that if they don't have access to the internet their ads are probably pretty terrible, or predefined within the apk. Most likely they are cross promoting ads like, "try our other apps", with some static play store url in them.

Comment: Thank you,I found it. I looked wrong. I thought that when I am installing an app from Play Store - "This application does not require any SPECIAL permissions". All is now clear. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internet access permission does not by default show up when you are downloading an app under the permissions that the app uses (i.e. "The app requires no special permissions to run." In this example the app could still use internet access. Google simply gave every app the permission, however you still need to declare that you use the permission in your application). If you have checked the permissions manually (using a program) and the application does not use the internet access permissions then the "ads" are likely just pictures that when clicked open your browser. Thus they require no internet access.

However to use admob the INTERNET ACCESS permission **is** required, the reason you don't see it is because Google no longer states whether application have this permission or not.

Comment: Thank you,I found it. I looked wrong. I thought that - when I am installing an app from Play Store - "This application does not require any SPECIAL permissions". All is now clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Internet permission is required now. Although, existing app with no Internet permission still works.